# Uninstalling XAMPP and its services

Tags: mysql, service, xampp, uninstallation

I have installed xampp while port 80 wasn't free. As a result one of the services wasn't able to run. Then I tried to reinstall the program as I thought it would replace any services that I had already installed. I ended up with having the other port being used from the previous MySQL service that had been downloaded when I firstly installed XAMPP.

I decided to uninstall xampp completely and reinstall it from the beginning. I've uninstalled XAMPP successfully, however when I check my program files the MySQL service is still there. I tried to delete it along with the other files but it says that I cannot complete the action because MySQL is in use.

How do I delete MySQL so that I can download XAMPP again from the beginning without any problems?

Comment: Also, the MySQL service is working good when I enter localhost however whenever I try to run the program from the start menu a message saying the program is already in use pops up. Finally, I was asked to use the program only with root

Answer (score 6):

To stop the Windows services, go to Start, Run, and type services.msc . Then, locate the Apache and MySQL services and stop them. If the XAMPP Control Panel is running close it.

To uninstall the Apache service, open a Command Prompt window with administrative privileges and execute the command:

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd -k uninstall

To uninstall the MySQL service, execute the command:

> sc delete mysql

If you used the ZIP archive to get XAMPP, you should be able to simply delete the XAMPP directory. If you used the installer, uninstall XAMPP from Programs in the Control Panel.

Comment: this is the only working solution

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL is running, you can access it via the command line interface:

`Start -> Type "Cmd" in the Search box -> click on program` (Windows 7)

Then in the command window you can use MySQL commands. If you want to manage MySQL databases via a *graphic UI* you have to use phpMyAdmin, which ships with XAMPP.

To Delete MySQL, first stop the windows service (if it's actually running as a service). You can view the running services by opening the management console:

```
Start -> Type "View Local Services" in the search box -> Click on the program
```

You can also view the services via the control panel. Find the MySQL service in the list and disable it, you should then be able to delete the program

If MySQL isn't running as a service but you still can't delete it you can either shut it down via the command line: `mysql> quit` or by killing the task in the windows task manager.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the whole Xammpp on your computer you get probably an error that not all the files can't be deleted. To delete the files without any problems go to 
task manager -> services -> services (with admin rights). Once you are their go and find 
mysql service and the Apache service. Stop those two servers and you can delete the other files at your xampp to get xampp deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For you to get rid of the `xampp` folder in your (c:) drive, Go to Start, type `msconfig` in the search bar and enter. In the start up program, disable `mysql` services and the `Apache` program. Restart your computer.you are now good to go.